# NModbus Write File Record

Tags: c#, modbus

Do you know by any chance if it is possible to use nmodbus to execute the Write File Record function (0x15)? I’m not able to find any mention of this in nmodbus documentation. I can see that the FtdAdapter has a Write function. Is it similar? What is the alternative to using nmodbus for this purpose?

Comment: I've checked the NModbus source code and now it is official: the Write File Record function is not supported. )) The question that remains is how do I submit this Modbus command using C#? Thanks!

Comment: If your slave device will accept an 0x15 modbus command, you can always try to create the byte message yourself and send it as a byte array.  I have always used this method in my Modbus applications with good success.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to do this is with the ExecuteCustomMessage method.

```
public TResponse ExecuteCustomMessage<TResponse>(IModbusMessage request) where TResponse : IModbusMessage, new()
```

See the IModbusMessage.cs documentation as you will have to implement this interface for request and response.

Also, see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/nmodbus/issues/detail?id=47). It seems like the latest NModbus download doesn't include the patch that adds support to custom messages for RTU, so the latest NModbus project source code must be obtained and compiled to get the latest nmodbus.dll.